# Collect similar terms in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, scientific-computing

I'm solving the [Maxwell Garnett equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Effective_medium_approximations) with SymPy:

```
solveset(Eq((e-m)/(e+2*m) = n*(a-m)/(a+2*m)), m)
```

[image]

Is it possible to simplify the solution by grouping similar terms together like Mathematica does?

[image]

The closest recipe I've found is [SymPy: How to collect multi-variable terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363674/sympy-how-to-collect-multi-variable-terms), but it is not directly applicable here.

I've progressed as far as:
[image]
But how do I get to the even more compact form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to call `collect` and give it a function that should apply to the coefficients after collection and so we can use factor to factorise the coefficients:

```
In [2]: e, a, m, n = symbols('e, a, m, n')

In [3]: sol = solveset(Eq((e-m)/(e+2*m), n*(a-m)/(a+2*m)), m)

In [4]: s1, s2 = sol.args[0]

In [5]: s1
Out[5]: 
                           _____________________________________________________________________________
                          ╱    2  2      2      2          2                       2  2      2        2 
2⋅a⋅n + a - e⋅n - 2⋅e   ╲╱  4⋅a ⋅n  + 4⋅a ⋅n + a  + 4⋅a⋅e⋅n  - 26⋅a⋅e⋅n + 4⋅a⋅e + e ⋅n  + 4⋅e ⋅n + 4⋅e  
───────────────────── - ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
      4⋅(n - 1)                                            4⋅(n - 1)                                    

In [6]: s1.collect(e, lambda c: c.factor() if c.is_polynomial() else c)
Out[6]: 
                              _______________________________________________________
                             ╱  2          2         ⎛   2           ⎞    2        2 
a⋅(2⋅n + 1) + e⋅(-n - 2)   ╲╱  a ⋅(2⋅n + 1)  + 2⋅a⋅e⋅⎝2⋅n  - 13⋅n + 2⎠ + e ⋅(n + 2)  
──────────────────────── - ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       4⋅(n - 1)                                   4⋅(n - 1)                         

In [7]: s2.collect(e, lambda c: c.factor() if c.is_polynomial() else c)
Out[7]: 
                              _______________________________________________________
                             ╱  2          2         ⎛   2           ⎞    2        2 
a⋅(2⋅n + 1) + e⋅(-n - 2)   ╲╱  a ⋅(2⋅n + 1)  + 2⋅a⋅e⋅⎝2⋅n  - 13⋅n + 2⎠ + e ⋅(n + 2)  
──────────────────────── + ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       4⋅(n - 1)                                   4⋅(n - 1)
```

The `is_polynomial` check is to stop `collect` from applying `factor` to the final expression after it is done recursing subexpressions (a final call to factor expands everything again). There might be a better check that could be used for more general situations.

Comment: I would definitely prefer if there was a more obvious way to do it, but at least it is possible! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is ill-defined. There are infinitely many ways to write a polynomial as a sum of products of polynomials. The completely expanded form is unique. If the whole polynomial can be factored over integers, this factorization is also unique. But writing it as a sum of products of polynomials can be done in infinitely many ways.

Comment: I'm fine with any of the ways. Mathematica doesn't consider it to be ill-defined. They just display the most compact form they could find.