# Sympy: Get coefficients of generic functions in an expression

Tags: python, sympy

I have equation (1) that linearly relates 3 functions of x, p,q,r.
I have equation (2) that linearly relates other 3 functions of x, s,q,r.
I want to obtain from (1) r in terms of p,q, and then substitute r in eqn. (2), to get a relation between s,p,q.
This is what I did in `sympy`.

```
p = sym.Function('p', real=True)
q = sym.Function('q', real=True)
r = sym.Function('r', real=True)
a1, a2, a3 = sym.symbols('a1, a2, a3', real=True, positive=True)

# 1. Solve for r in terms of p, q, from Eqn. (1)
# (2*a2+1)*(a1-1)*px = (2*a2+1)*B*qx + (2*a2+1)*B*(a3-1)*rx
px = p(x)
qx = q(x)
rx = r(x)
expr_p_qr = (2*a2+1)*B*qx + (2*a2+1)*B*(a3-1)*rx
r_sol = sym.simplify(sym.solve((2*a2+1)*(a1-1)*px - expr_p_qr, rx, dict=True))
r1 = r_sol[0][rx]
print('r(x) =', r1)

# 2. Substitute r in Eqn. (2)
# sx + qx - rx = 0
s = sym.Function('s', real=True)
sx = s(x)
expr_sqr = sx + qx - rx
expr_sqrb = sym.simplify(expr_sqr.subs([(rx, r1)]))
print('expr_sqr:', expr_sqrb, '= 0')
```

and I get

```
r(x) = (-B*q(x) + a1*p(x) - p(x))/(B*(a3 - 1))
expr_sqr: (B*(a3 - 1)*(q(x) + s(x)) + B*q(x) - a1*p(x) + p(x))/(B*(a3 - 1)) = 0
```

Now I want to get simplified coefficients of (s,p,q)(x).
I couldn't manage to do so on the whole expression.

Moreover, I tried to do it somewhat "manually", by extracting the coefficients.
And I failed as well, with

```
cs = expr_sqrb.coeff(sx)
cp = expr_sqrb.coeff(px)
cq = expr_sqrb.coeff(qx)
print(cs, cp, cq)
```

which gives

```
0 0 0
```

How can I solve this?

**Related**:

1. [SymPy: How to collect multi-variable terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363674/sympy-how-to-collect-multi-variable-terms)
2. [Best way to isolate one coefficient of a multivariate polynomial in sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36818025/best-way-to-isolate-one-coefficient-of-a-multivariate-polynomial-in-sympy)

Comment: You could use `expand` and `collect`, then `coeff`. Probably I would use `expr_sqrb.as_poly(sx, px, qx)`.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin - Your suggestion worked well. I suggest you post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin - The result is given in terms of a Poly object. Is there a way to extract each of the coefficients individually? ... 
Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60552819/2707864). It is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[How to extract all coefficients in sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955888/how-to-extract-all-coefficients-in-sympy) is a related question, with some overlap with this one, although it is not exactly the same.
Proof of that:
The most voted answer (which contains the accepted answer) does not work in this case, error: `PolynomialError: multivariate polynomials not supported`.

A [less voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60552819/2707864), which covers the more general case of multivariate polynomials, works fine here.